# Forwarding original URI within mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use mod_rewrite and somehow forward - preferably via a header - the original URI to my application server.

What I'm really sticking up on is how to get the information I send to carry over from the client after they follow the redirect to the application server.

The only method I've come up with is passing a get request with original URI, but that seems ugly.

Note - I already reviewed [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever) and [Crazy Advanced Mod_Rewrite Debug Tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/crazy-advanced-mod_rewrite-tutorial.html#RequestHeader_htaccess)

It's possible I overlooked something; if so please give me the right term and close as a duplicate. :)

EDIT:

mod_rewrite is using a 302 redirect to the application server. The actual redirect is client side. 
Some of the domains match, others don't.  The basic syntax of my rules looks like the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain|myalias
RewriteRule ^ http://www.mydomain.org... [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your rewrite rules, save the URI into a variable. I'll call it ORIGINAL_URI.

```
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=ORIGINAL_URI:$1]
```

Is Apache directly passing this request along to the application server? If so, set a custom [header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html), which I'll call Original-URI, to the value of that variable.

```
RequestHeader set "Original-URI" "%{ORIGINAL_URI}e"
```

Is Apache sending a redirect back to the client, which will then issue a new request?  As long as the domain stays the same, you could tell the client to set a cookie.

```
Header set Set-Cookie "Original-URI=%{ORIGINAL_URI}e"
```

Comment: Sorry, should have included additional details in my original post. I've edited additional details in.